# VS 2013 ultimate editor - missing the button to build CSS 'style' in properties window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editor, visual-studio-2013

I recently upgraded from Visual studio 2010 to VS 2013 ultimate.
In VS2010 editor, whenever I have cursor in a HTML tag or a CSS class, the 'Style' item in the property window would have that '...' button to help me launch Style builder window where I could easily build by style properties. This '...' button is not visible in the 'Style' item of properties window VS 2013. Am I missing anything?

Comment: It's not here for me too. Maybe because inline styles are **BAD**?

Comment: but its not there for building the css class too :(

Comment: The intellisense has improved so much, that it's easier to just do it in the editor I suppose... Fact is, that it's no longer there.

Comment: I find that mostly the IntelliSense (and Googling) is sufficient. From time to time I use Microsoft Expression Web to view/edit the css files. Gives a different view/feel, and has an advanced/extended version over the old style-builder